# Are independent random variable thresholds applied to a constant independent?

Tags: random-variables, independence, covariance, correlation

Let $x$ be a number within (0,1) and let $Y_{i}$ be a uniform RV $Y_{i}\sim U(0,1)$. We define function $f_{i}(x)$ such that:

$$
f_{i}(x) =\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      1, & \mbox{if $x>Y_{i}$}\\
      0, & \mbox{otherwise}
    \end{array}
  \right.
$$

Are $f_{1}(x)$ and $f_{2}(x)$ IID?

My intuition is that they are not because $x$ is obviously correlated with itself. However, I am having trouble coming up with a proof given that $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ are clearly IID.

Comment: Your notation is confusing. Your definition of $f$ appears to depend on $i$ but there's no $i$ on the left-hand side. By $f(x_1),f(x_2)$ do you really mean something like $f_1(x),f_2(x)$?

Comment: Karl I have updated the question for better clarity in the notation as you suggested thanks.

Comment: Your reasoning would make sense if $x$ were a non-constant random variable, because then (intuitively speaking) knowing $f_1(x)$ could give you information about $x$, which in turn could give you information about $f_2(x)$, making the values non-independent. But since $x$ is a constant, there's no such effect. Independent variables will remain independent after you apply deterministic functions to them.

Comment: In fact, a constant random variable is independent from itself.

Comment: In this case x is just an input, not a RV though. $f_{i}(x)$ is only a RV via the threshold created by $Y_{i}$. Does that change things?

Comment: That doesn't change things - "$f_i(x)$" is just the notation you've defined for an expression that depends on both $Y_i$ and $x$. We could just as well call it $f_x(Y_i)$ or $f(x,Y_i)$ (or $1_{x>Y_i}$, as it's an [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)). It's probably clearest to avoid "hiding randomness" in the function symbol.

Comment: $f(x,Y_{i})$ is a better expression for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $Y_i$ are generated independently, then $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ with $x_1=x_2$ are IID. For example, in the first trial you generate a number from the uniform distribution ($Y_1$) and then using that number you calculate $f(\frac{1}{2})$. In the second trial you generate another random number from the uniform distribution ($Y_2$), independently from the first random number in the first trial, and then again you calculate $f(\frac{1}{2})$. In both triales, we don't care $x_1=x_2=\frac{1}{2}$. Generating $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ doesn't depend on $x$, because first you generate them and then you compare with $x$.

First we show they are identically distributed. It is sufficient to show that
they have the same cumulative distribution functions (CDF).

Let $F$ and $G$ be CDFs of $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ respectively and let $0 \leq z < 1 $. We have,

$$F(z) = P(f(x_1) \leq z) = P(f(x_1) = 0) = P(Y \geq x_1) = 1-x_1.$$

so  $$F(z) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & z < 0 \\
      1-x_1 & 0\leq z < 1 \\
      1 &  z \geq 1 
   \end{cases}$$

Similarly

$$G(z) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & z < 0 \\
      1-x_2 & 0\leq z < 1 \\
      1 &  z \geq 1 
   \end{cases}$$
if $x_1=x_2$, then $F(z) = G(z)$ for all $z$ and this means they have the same distributions.

It is left to show they are independent. Let $0 \leq y,z <1 $,

$$P(f(x_1) \leq y, f(x_2) \leq z) = P(Y_1 \geq x_1, Y_2 \geq  x_2) = P(Y_1 \geq x_1)P(Y_2 \geq x_2) = P(f(x_1) \leq y) P(f(x_2) \leq z).$$

Other cases for $y$ and $z$ can be also checked.

Comment: Dan the overall reasoning looks correct. For independence though, how are you getting $P(Y_{1}=0,Y_{2}=0}$? Is it not?: $P(f(x_{1})\le y,f(x_{2})\le z)= P(f(x_{1})=0,f(x_{2})=0) = P(Y_{1}\ge x_{1},Y_{2}\ge x_{2}) = P(Y_{1}\ge x_{1},Y_{2}\ge x_{1}) = P(Y_{1}\ge x_{1})P(Y_{2}\ge x_{1}) = P(f(x_{1})\le y)P(f(x_{2})\le z)$

Comment: Yes, I fixed that.